# what should be the order_id field when working with razor pay payment gateway testmode in andriod

Tags: android, razorpay

I want to know what will be the `order_id` to pass in my android code while working with `Razor pay` payment gateway in test mode.

Comment: You have to create an order_id from your server side [as stated in step 3](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/android-integration/standard/) and get it in response of any api call

Comment: but what if i am using test mode?

Comment: You can test the checkout in `sandbox` mode using [test cards](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/test-card-upi-details/)

Comment: Thanks man. It worked

Comment: please refer the official documentation - https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/

Answer (score 1):

Lets me put it in a simple way.

U need to first make an API call to Razorpay with details like amount and currency.

Razorpay would return an order id, this orderid needs to be passed in options object before opening the checkout pafe.

please refer to this [link](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/#create-an-order) for details on how to create an order id.

Answer (score 0):

in order id, it should your predefined set value or unique create id for each customer order request so you can find customer order detail easily

lest understand with an example

by default on a payment, time is null after successfully payment completed then created order id automatically as per your logic these order id set into your database with orders items.

so after ordering you can find your order status easily...

a simple example is Flipkart ,amazon after checkout you get and orderid

Comment: can you explain properly?

Comment: order id does not require in payment gateway test mode or any mode because after payment complete or cod option select then after your order is created.

Comment: you can check  bais flowchart e-commerce or database relationship or er-diagram visit it   please visit https://landing.moqups.com/img/content/diagrams/erd/ecommerce/ecommerce-1600.png   http://www.mysqltutorial.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/MySQL-Sample-Database-Schema.png

Comment: @axar dude it is regarding **`razor pay`** he is not asking any general logic about order id and FYI it is a required field if you are using razor pay sdk. During checkout you have to send the `order id` from client side otherwise it will throw an error. You should generate order id from your server side code and send that to your client side before checking out.

Comment: so you have to create the first ordered Id  from the server-side using web services rest API on payment after getting the order id then you have to call start Razorpay  see example  https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/android-integration/standard/